# Python + Celery + SQLAlchemy(sqlite) -> does not work as expected

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, celery

i currently have problems running celery or celery-worker in with SQLAlchemy problably (sqlite memory db).

Here is my simple setup:

**proj/db.py:** (simple db with sqlalchemy and scoped_sessions)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', convert_unicode=True, pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=10, echo=False)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" %     (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

**proj/celery.py** (celery config, including proj.tasks)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
import config

celery = Celery('app', broker='redis://{}:{}/{}'.format(config.R_HOST,    config.R_PORT, config.R_DB),
            backend='redis://{}:{}/{}'.format(config.R_HOST, config.R_PORT, config.R_DB),
            include=["proj.tasks"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

**proj/tasks.py** (simple tasks to read and write to db)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from proj.celery import celery
from proj.db import db_session, User
from celery import Task

class SqlAlchemyTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        db_session.remove()


@celery.task(base=SqlAlchemyTask)
def setdb():
    u = User(id=10, name="NAME", fullname="FULL", password="PASS")
    db_session.add(u)
    db_session.commit()
    print("INSERT")

@celery.task(base=SqlAlchemyTask)
def get_from_db():
    print(db_session.query(User).all())
```

**config.py** (config-file)

```
R_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
R_PORT = 6379
R_DB = 0
```

**run.py** (the file that is executed)

```
from proj.db import db_session
from proj.db import User
from proj.tasks import get_from_db, setdb
import time

setdb.apply_async()
time.sleep(10)
get_from_db.apply_async()
get_from_db.apply_async()
get_from_db.apply_async()
get_from_db.apply_async()
time.sleep(10)
print(db_session.query(User).all())
```

---

If I now start the redis-server, celery and then run the run.py some weird stuff happened. My programm inserts a entry in the database through the `setdb.apply_async()` call. After 10 seconds, the programm querys data with the `get_from_db.apply_async()`. All this is done by celery. I expect all workers to have access to the inserted data, but the celery log shows something else.

**celery log**

```
celery -A proj worker

[2018-08-11 11:32:34,959: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] INSERT
[2018-08-11 11:32:40,767: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-1] []
[2018-08-11 11:32:40,769: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-3] []
[2018-08-11 11:32:40,771: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-4] []
[2018-08-11 11:32:40,773: WARNING/SpawnPoolWorker-2] [<User(name='NAME', fullname='FULL', password='PASS')>]
```

Also the main programm dont see any data (`print(db_session.query(User).all())`):
**python run.py**

```
[]
```

Although celery-worker 2 inserts an entry, no data is visible in the database from other workers or the main program (run.py).
How can i fix this problem so that i can access the same data in every worker and in the main program. Regardless of which worker entered them ?

Greets Jeff

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#pysqlite-threading-pooling and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads, at the moment each thread has its own private in-memory database.